# When receiving a call, how do you mute the phone?

Tags: audio, mute

This might seem like a stupid question, but I couldn't find the answer on this SE so here goes. When I receive a call and my phone starts to ring, how do I mute the phone without answering or dismissing the call? Is this done differently depending on the Android OS version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just press any volume button while its ringing.
On side note, make sure there isnt an option like `answer by volume buttons` in `settings->accessibility`. If there is, make sure its disabled. If its not there, then you are fine ;)
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this seems to work well. I tested it by having a friend call me (I am using Lollipop) and pressed either volume up or volume down to mute the incoming call without dismissing or answering the call. Also I noticed that simply pressing the power button will do the same muting, same way as with iPhones. Seems to work also when the screen is locked.

Comment: Glad  your query is solved, good luck :-)